# Parse data through my website using cron jobs

Tags: javascript, php, cron, setcookie

There are few hosting providers which does something like this when you visit the URL hosted there. 
Like for example, consider a hosting provider, say "xtreemhost.com"

A website is hosted there, say, "vritrasur.com"

What the site does is, if we visit the site, "http://vritrasur.com", it will update the url to "http://vritrasur.com/?i=1"

If you again reload it, it becomes, "http://vritrasur.com/?i=2"

The problem:

I have a php script, uploaded in one of such website (my website only, just hosted in one of such server), and i need to run that script every hour.
Because its foolishness to do it manually, i thought to put a cron job for it.

Whenever cron jobs makes the request, the url throws an error like this

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script>
        <script>
            function toNumbers(d){
                var e=[];
                d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d) { e.push(parseInt(d,16)) });
                return e
            }
            function toHex(){
                for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;
                f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);
                return e.toLowerCase()
            }
            var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("9f38f758d71e0c6e0e935c8c90e0cce1");
            document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; 
            expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; 
            location.href="http://raghavrao.com/homeimage/reasontorely/infra1.png?i=1";
        </script>
        <noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

Technically, the server is setting some cookie in my browser, and is then is updating the URL, thus preventing any automated bots to scrap data through their servers.

My question is, will it be possible to scrap even after such hurdles.

If yes, please show me how.

Answer (score 0):

After research i can see that Google has indexed the website vritrasur.com with https://www.google.nl/#q=site:vritrasur.com and Google is an automated bot so i've tried the useragent "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)" and i was in without javascript and __test cookie.

PHP code i used to get in rest off the code is up to you

```
<?php 

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://vritrasur.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)");

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: sir, im using cron jobs, which only allows me to set the url.

Comment: because, i cannot use curl, how could i manage to set the useragent?

Comment: @yogesh prajapati please elaborate more an cronjob is just an scheduled task it cant scrap a website without some program.

Comment: the scheduled task is just to visit a URL, and that URL is actually my php script which gets fired